# Avoid repetition of same logic

Tags: kotlin, coding-style

I have the following data classes:

```
sealed class ExampleDto

object Type1ExampleDto : ExampleDto()

object Type2ExampleDto : ExampleDto()

data class Type3ExampleDto(val name: Int, val age: Int) : ExampleDto()

data class Type4ExampleDto(val name: Int, val age: Int) : ExampleDto()

data class Type5ExampleDto(val email: String) : ExampleDto()

data class Type6ExampleDto(val name: Int, val age: Int, val email: String) : ExampleDto()
```

In particular, `Type3ExampleDto`, `Type4ExampleDto` and `Type6ExampleDto` share some common fields but it's important for my business logic to distinguish between **types** (i.e. even if `Type3ExampleDto` and `Type4ExampleDto` are identical, I have to know if I'm in the **type3** or **type4** case).

In one of my method I have the following call:

```
when (type) {
            is Type3ExampleDto -> myMethod(type.vote, type.text)
            is Type4ExampleDto -> myMethod(type.vote, type.text)
            is Type6ExampleDto -> myMethod(type.vote, type.text)
            else -> null
        }
```

I find very ugly that I'm doing the same operation in all 3 cases and repeating the same line...

It makes sense to made `Type3ExampleDto`, `Type4ExampleDto` and `Type6ExampleDto` an implementation of some kind of interface just because **only** in this point I'm doing this kind of ugly repetition?

If all three dtos implement the following interface

```
interface MyInterface{
fun getVote() : Int
fun getText() : String

}
```

I can write:

```
if (type is MyInterface) {
    myMethod(type.getVote(), type.getText())
}
```

So, it's acceptable to create this interface just to solve this isolated repetition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you can do it much more cleanly like this:

```
interface NameAndAgeDto {
    val name: Int
    val age: Int
}

data class Type3ExampleDto(override val name: Int, override val age: Int) : ExampleDto(), NameAndAgeDto

if (type is NameAndAgeDto) {
    myMethod(type.name, type.age)
}
```

Whether it's "acceptable" is opinion. Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

You may change your model to have your logic based on **behaviour instead of inheritance**.
This way of modelling is based on principles of (but ain't exactly) *Strategy Design Pattern*.

```
interface HasName {
    val name: String
}

interface HasAge {
    val age: Int
}

interface HasEmail {
    val email: String
}

object Type1

object Type2

data class Type3(
        override val name: String,
        override val age: Int
) : HasName, HasAge

data class Type4(
        override val name: String,
        override val age: Int
) : HasName, HasAge

data class Type5(
        override val email: String
) : HasEmail

data class Type6(
        override val name: String,
        override val age: Int,
        override val email: String
) : HasName, HasAge, HasEmail

// Then you can pass any object to it.
fun main(obj: Any) {
    // Koltin type-casts it nicely to both interfaces.
    if (obj is HasName && obj is HasAge) {
        myMethod(text = obj.name, vote = obj.age)
    }
}

fun myMethod(vote: Int, text: String) {

}
```

If you still want all the types to belong to some parent type, you can use **marker interface** (without any methods).

```
interface DTO

interface HasName {
    val name: String
}

interface HasAge {
    val age: Int
}

interface HasEmail {
    val email: String
}

object Type1 : DTO

object Type2 : DTO

data class Type3(
        override val name: String,
        override val age: Int
) : HasName, HasAge, DTO

data class Type4(
        override val name: String,
        override val age: Int
) : HasName, HasAge, DTO

data class Type5(
        override val email: String
) : HasEmail, DTO

data class Type6(
        override val name: String,
        override val age: Int,
        override val email: String
) : HasName, HasAge, HasEmail, DTO

// Here, it is DTO instead of Any
fun main(obj: DTO) {
    if (obj is HasName && obj is HasAge) {
        myMethod(text = obj.name, vote = obj.age)
    }
}
```

And use `sealed` class instead of marker `interface` if you need **classes as enum**.
In that case, `when` over `sealed class` is exhaustive with all options without `null ->`.